# Should I use a library for Icons or manually download Icons into my ReactJs project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, frontend, icons

I am developing a website using React Js.
My question is simple: When using icons, should I download them manually (as SVG) ?
Or is it better to import icons via an icon library?

Which of the two methods will make my website run faster?

I already have made a design in Figma and there I used icons too...
I was planning to download those icons from Figma and use them in my project (so downloading icons manually), since I am tight on time right now.

But if this is not the most efficient way to put icons in a website I can reconsider my choice.

Answer (score 3):

Using an icon library saves you the hassle of manually including icons in your project directory. You can try this [React icons library](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/)

This project utilizes ES6 imports that allows you to include only the icons that your project is using. Therefore giving you a smaller bundle size